# Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 0 on Python POST request to Firebase

Tags: python, json, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send a message via Firebase to a certain client. This is my current (test) code:

```
import json
import requests
import urllib

def send_message():
    server = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
    api_key = "xxx"
    user_token = "xxx"

    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'key=' + api_key}

    data = {"type": "dataUpdate"}
    payload = {"data": data, "to": user_token}
    payload = json.dumps(payload)

    res = requests.post(server, headers=headers, json=payload)

    return res
```

which produces the following error, returned by Firebase:

```
JSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 0.
```

The following JSON sent to Firebase seems correct to me:

```
{  
   "data": {  
      "type":"dataUpdate"
   },
   "to":"xxx"
}
```

which is in the format described by the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_specific_devices). Any idea why Firebase doesn't accept the given data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `json=payload` as a parameter to `requests.post()` you don't need to specify `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` in the header.  In addition, you are passing a string when the parameter should be `payload` as a dict (ie. no need for `json.dumps()`)

Try this:

```
def send_message():
    server = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
    api_key = "xxx"
    user_token = "xxx"

    headers = {'Authorization': 'key=' + api_key}

    data = {"type": "dataUpdate"}
    payload = {"data": data, "to": user_token}

    res = requests.post(server, headers=headers, json=payload)

    return res
```

Comment: @OpenUserX03 Why does setting the content-type:application/json header cause the request to fail? I am worried because something like that could happen mistakenly.

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda it shouldn't, it just is unnecessary if you specify the `json` parameter